# When I submit this form, neither data is saved onto database nor giving any error in my django project

Tags: python, html, django

models.py
**here is my model**

```
class Load_post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pick_up_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    destination_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False , blank=False , unique=True)
    receiver_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    sending_item = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    metric_unit = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='SOME STRING')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    requested_shiiping_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pick_up_time = models.DateField()
    drop_time = models.DateField()
    paid_by = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('local')

class Meta:
    ordering = ["-created_at"]
    unique_together = ["sender_name", "receiver_name"]
```

**please check the phone number**

forms.py

**this is form.py**

```
class Loader_post_form(forms.ModelForm):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    metric_unit = forms.ChoiceField(choices=UNIT, required=True)

class Meta:
    model = Load_post
    fields = ("pick_up_station", "destination_station",
              "sender_name", "phone_number", "receiver_name",
              "sending_item","image_of_load","weight","metric_unit",
              "quantity","requested_shiiping_price","pick_up_time",
              "drop_time","paid_by")
```

views.py
**This is my views.py
absolute URL used in models already**

```
class Loader_post_view(CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    login_url = 'Driver/login/'
    form_class = forms.Loader_post_form
    model = Loader_Signup
    template_name = "Driver/post.html"

def form_valid(self,form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.save()
    return super(Loader_post_view,self).form_valid(form)
```

post.html
**this is html page (template)**

```
    {% extends "Driver/base.html" %} 
    {% block content %}
    <h1>create a post</h1>
    {% csrf_token %} 
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit">submit</button> 
    {% endblock content %}
```

this is html code

**how to add it to the database
and I cannot see any error in my forms 
thank you**
am working on driver and client-side project

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you html template cannot submit the form because you ae missing the `<form>` tags - if you do not have them hidden in your base.html.

Your html template should be something like this:

```
{% extends "Driver/base.html" %} 
    {% block content %}
    <h1>create a post</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        {{form}}
        <button type="submit">submit</button> 
    </form>
    {% endblock content %}
```

The `{{ form }}` renders the form with all the inputs but does not create the  tags needed for html forms.

In addition there are some other errors in the code you posted.

In your view the model you defined is called `Loader_Signup`, however the model you posted is `Load_post`. Either you posted the wrong model or you declared the wrong model in your view.

In your form one field is called `image_of_load`, however, this field is not part of you model.

In your model you have got a field called `phone_number`, you are defining a field with the same name in your form. The field in your form has got no connection to your model so take it out.

Unfortunately you are not providing any details about your PhoneNumberField so this cannot be checked.

Comment: @dilmeetpadda Please try providing more details about errors and what your are experiencing with your code (e.g. is the form being submitted, are you seeing any traceback errors, have you tried debugging). The code you posted contains a number of errors, I updated my answer with the errors I found. So if you made the change I posted in my first answer you should have seen errors which could have been helpful to post

Comment: thank sir ... it's working the form tag wasn't  close properly